# How can I read a compressed RDF zip using clj-plaza ?

Tags: clojure, rdf, freebase

I have recently got hold of Freebase's RDF [dump](https://developers.google.com/freebase/data). It is a compressed zip file which is around 25GB, but the uncompressed version can go upto 250GB.
I have all set it up on an EC2 instance.

There is a note that reads:

> If you're writing your own code to parse the RDF dumps its often more efficient to read directly from GZip file rather than extracting the data first and then processing the uncompressed data.

I just started looking into clj-plaza to query RDFs, now I am wondering how do I read this data without unzipping the file ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
(with-open [stream (java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.
                     (clojure.java.io/input-stream
                       (clojure.java.io/file "my-file.zip")))]
  (document-to-model stream :ntriple))
```

Having referred [plaza.rdf.core](https://github.com/antoniogarrote/clj-plaza/blob/master/src/plaza/rdf/core.clj)

Should do the trick?
(stream the data).